# Every time App Show alert view for apple-id at the starting of the app in IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am using in-app purchase in my apps but from last 1 week my apps showing `alertview` for `apple-id login` as user start the app. What is the issue with Apple? Why its appear again and again? I have not made any change in my apps for 2 months.